# .vcxproj didn't update immediately

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

When I changing some project properties in the Visual Studio.The .vcxproj file did not updating immediately.But when I close the solution,it shows up that ask me to save the file.How can I update the .vcxproj when I change some properties?

Comment: Click the "Save All" toolbar button.  Or use File > Save All.  Or type the shortcut keystroke, typically Ctrl+Shift+S.

Comment: Hans has pointed out the answer. Every time when you make changes in VS project properties, the project file won't be updated(you can check the Date Modified time before and after save button) until you save the changes.

Comment: I'm developing a VS extension programme.How can I save the changes when I click my visx command buttion that can save the changes?

Comment: If you want to save all the project properties when you click the command button, you can use `ExecuteCommand` method, call this method to execute the `Save all `command in VS. It can works to save changes of project properties and documents while [Documents.SaveAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.documents.saveall?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) only works to save document files instead of project file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [_DTE.ExecuteCommand(String, String) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte._dte.executecommand?view=visualstudiosdk-2017).

```
            DTE dTE=Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(DTE)) as DTE;
            dTE.ExecuteCommand("File.SaveAll");
```

It works to programmatically call the `Save All` command of VS. It will save changes for all modified document files and project files(which can update the .xxproj file). So use the code in the method which will execute after your command button is clicked.